# Google api console : 3 Client ID for installed applications with same package and different sha1 key

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

In Google API console for Android application, how to create multiple client id for the same application with same package name and different sha1 keys?

For single client it works perfectly, when I add the second sha1 key with same package rest of the one is not working.

How can I create the multiple client id for same application with same package name?

Answer (score 1):

Simply generate a ClientID for your app. Thenk you'll see that under the "Client ID for installed applications" table there is a "Create another client ID..." button. Use it to add another client ID for the same app with different SHA1.

The only negative consequence is that you have to provide your package name, icon and project name for *every* clientID, so if something has to be changed it has to be changed for every clientID

Comment: I'm facing same problem. I have 2 client IDs. One for DEbug and the other for release. I have don't have problems debugging, but I have them when using the APK signed with the release key. My client IDs are something like: "<ProjectID>.apps.googleusercontent.com" (debug). "<ProjectID>- <randomString>.apps.googleusercontent.com" (release). Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you use the new cloud console? Under "APIs & auth" there is a "Register apps" page where you can register multiple apps* with different SHA1s and the same package name. This works for me and I am able to use the same package name for debug and release builds (signed with different certificates).
Do you use the clientIDs explicitly or you let the GooglePlayServices do the authentication for your app?

*those apps will have the same consent screen